# configure that /etc/resolv.conf won't be modified after restart

Tags: domain-name-system, gentoo, static-ip, resolv.conf

I have Gentoo Linux amd64 installed on one of my computers.
I have a static IP configured at /etc/conf.d/net:

```
auto_eth0="true"
config_eth0="192.168.1.2/24"
routes_eth0="default via 192.168.1.1"
enable_ipv6_eth0="false"
```

I manually edited /etc/resolv.conf and added google dns servers.
the problem is that whenever I restart my server /etc/resolv.conf gets wiped out. 
I tired setting 'chmod a-w /etc/resolv.conf' and it didn't work but i actually don't really like that method anyhow.

how can I let gentoo know that I don't want /etc/resolv.conf to be modified ?

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this these days is, I believe, to add the DNS information to your `/etc/conf.d/net` file, so that the rc scripts manage your `/etc/resolv.conf` file correctly.

Add:

```
dns_servers="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

to that file and you should be good to go. If you need other resolver settings, look at the `net.example` file in `/usr/share/doc/openrc-*/`. Some of the available settings:

```
dns_domain
dns_search
dns_options
dns_sortlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you will ever need to change resolv.conf just remove immutable flag by:

```
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: While this might prevent whatever process overwriting this file it does not really address the root of the issue.  @Mat's answer seems to be the better approach.

Comment: That's true, @Mat's approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo requires that DNS configuration be added to `/etc/conf.d/net` in order to be retained after a reboot. Your net file would look something like this:

```
config_eth0="192.168.1.2/24"
routes_eth0="default via 192.168.1.1"
dns_servers_eth0="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

Similarly, if you wish to specify an interface-independant DNS server (ie. this setting will apply  for all interfaces) you can simply use the `dns_servers` directive, without appending the interface:

```
config_eth0="192.168.1.2/24"
routes_eth0="default via 192.168.1.1"

dns_servers="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

> dhcp_eth0="nodns"

to your `/etc/conf.d/net` to prevent overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score -2):

In Debian Linux your DNS servers change after a reboot.

1. Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file

   ```
   nameserver ...........
   nameserver ..........
   search  domainname
   ```

   save and exit.
2. `/etc/init.d/networking restart`
3. `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`
4. Reboot system

Comment: it's working..............